# Eigen value of a complex block matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

I have a following block matrix

```
M1 =([a11 a12;a21 a22] [b13;b23];[b13;b23]' d33) + ([c -cr]'*[c -cr] 0;0 I)
```

now what i observe is that whether i use `[c -cr]'*[c -cr]` or `[c cr]'*[c cr]` (the sign change in `cr` the eigen value of M1 doesn't change. How can i prove this in general? Or this is just a co-incidence that, with the examples i am running there is no change in eigen values of M1 with the sign changes.
Please I am really looking forward for your answers. Thanks in advance.

All the elements of M1 are matrices of appropriate dimensions.

Comment: The above notations are strange, although I could try to guess what you mean. Can you explain more? Is this some language in Maple, Sage, Mathematica, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you can understand it like there is a M1 which is the sum of two matrices e.g., M1 = Ma + Mb. Now for Mb matrix the eigen values doesn't change with changing signs of cr (i can prove this by using a similar matrix technique which P = [I 0 0;0 -I 0;0 0 I] where I is the identity matrix of appropriate dimension... Now the question is that what will be the net effect of no change of eigen value of Mb on M1? I hope it clearfy the question a bit

Comment: Does $M_1$ look like$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&b_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&b_{23}\\b_{13}&b_{23}&d_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: its like &M1&
\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&0&b_{13}\\0&a_{22}&b_{23}\\b_{13}^\top &b_{23}^\top&d_{33}\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}c^\top c &-cc_r&0\\-c_r c&c_rc_r&0\\0 &0 &I\end{pmatrix} \end{align}

Comment: Also, what's meant by (') followed by a star.
I assume (') is transpose?

Comment: I am new here, unable to type the problem correctly.
The second matrix in the sum is
\begin{pmatrix} c^\top c&-c^\top c_r&0\\-c_r^\top c&c_r^\top c_r&0\\0&0&I \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Oh I understand now that star is matrix multiplication! Thanks!

Comment: Now the problem is with the signs of 'c^\top c_r' and 'c_r^\top c' as they change their signs the eigen values doesn't change. what will be the effect of this on the whole M1... this is my question. I hope that i am able to put my question correctly.
I feel extremely sorry for this mess of comments :(